# How do I reject an edit to my answer

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Someone [edited one of my answers](https://superuser.com/a/445137/4377) (actually edited the same answer twice in 2 days), and BOTH edits were approved by other people (reviewers, I assume). The edits were BOTH very minor and only added 1 external link. That exact link was already mentioned TWICE in the QUESTION, so adding it to the answer is not only "minor", but it adds nothing of value.

In any case, the text and link that were added points to incomplete information that contains only partial information about "Command-line options", not what I would consider full "Documentation". I had the opportunity to add this information when I wrote the answer but I intentionally left it out because it is incomplete and was already included within the question.

Do I get a chance to "Reject" an edit to my Answer (if so, how)?, or do I just have to edit the answer a third time to remove (rollback) the other person's 2 edits?

Comment: @Sathya - the answer is here: http://superuser.com/a/445137/144147

Comment: Also, you should consider deleting `Edit (danpritts)` from the post - It's just stupid and adds nothing. I don't want to do it because then it'll look like I'm piggybacking on all the edits.

Answer (score 1):

While reviewing, the reviewers have the option to reject an edit - you also get a notification when an edit is suggested, so you can go ahead and reject that edit.

If the edit has been approved, you can always pull up the revisions by clicking on the last edit timestamp & then choose the revision to which you can rollback to.

[image]

---

Now, wrt to this edit - is the editor Minor? I think not. Do they refer to the same documentation? I'd argue not - you've linked to the one which applies to

> Applies To: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2

whereas the edit links to documentation which applies to

> Applies To: Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012

I haven't gone & done a diff of the two versions to see if there's any difference, but having an answer which links to the latest revision of the document is always preferable.

Comment: The linked webpage is very old, and has only been changed to reflect that it applies to more recent operating systems. It is incomplete and only provides a minimal command line reference. It is missing a lot of information, and has less information than typing "Robocopy /help" at a command prompt. There is no documentation explaining any of the commands or how they interact with one another. The other documents linked in my answer are "older", but are still fully valid and are only missing info about a couple newer command line options that can be seen with "Robocopy /help".

Comment: [This edit](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/155846) never should have been approved, no matter how good the link is. "*Edit (danpritts) - They…*"

Comment: @KevinFegan when you're reviewing, you're reviewing *only* the answer, the question is not shown for context. So having a link added on to the answer isn't inherently bad, especially when none of your existing answer is being changed. Like I said, if you don't like it, you can always chose to roll it back.

Comment: The biggest reason is, the question asker mentions that link, but the information they are looking for is not on that page (as I said, minimal and incomplete). So to include it in an answer is incorrect as the link is known to not contain enough information to answer the question that was asked. Further, including it may lead other answer seekers to follow that link (over the other links) to find a page that does not help. Just to clarify, the info at the page in question amounts to about 7 pages out of the 35 pages in the PDF doc I linked to.

Comment: Although I appreciate and understand it's apparently the only way, but I don't particularly like the option of simply doing a rollback, as that just unnecessarily increases the edit count. For now, I'll add a comment, and I'll reserve removing the edit until I have additional information to add to the answer. Also thanks for your clarification about the review process.

Comment: @KevinFegan - So you will make a comment which increases the the version count instead of removing the comment by dan which is an invalid edit.  I agree with daniel in that neither edit should have been approved.  **If it was just a linkification of text I would agree with the edit but it wasn't.**

Comment: @Ramhound - "*...comment which increases the the version count...*" I'm talking about adding a comment to the answer, not a comment within the answer. If I could I would just "Reject" the edits which would set the edits-count from 7, back to 5, but I guess that's not possible. I could be wrong, but I seem to recall that if I do a rollback to edit-5, the rollback will show as edit-8. If that's the case, I'd rather wait until I have something useful to add and do it all at once. I'm really not sure what I want to do or what I should do. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @DanielBeck Do I win a prize for being the only person who rejected [that edit](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/155846)? :)